# Why the record is deleting on clicking Cancel in a confirmation box, using knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, onclick

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Items">

        <tr>                            
            <td data-bind="text: Code"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: SubscriptionName"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Type"></td>
            <td data-bind="dateText: StartDate, dateFormat: 'MM/DD/YYYY'"></td>
            <td data-bind="dateText: ExpirationDate, dateFormat: 'MM/DD/YYYY'"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: IsOneTime"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: ValueDisplayType"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: IsAvailable"></td>                            
            <td>
                <a data-bind="attr: { href: '/couponcode/edit/' + ID() }"><i class="icon-edit"></i> Edit</a> |                                        
                <a data-bind="click: $root.deletedata" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this record?');"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</a>                                
            </td>                            
        </tr>

    </tbody>





    <script type="text/javascript">
    var couponModel = ko.buildAjaxModel("@ConfigManager.Application.BuildApiUrl("couponcode/get/coupons")", CouponModel.Mapping, function () {
                    console.log(couponModel);
                }, function (item) {

                    console.log(item);
                }, true);
    //This is the working of deletion
                couponModel.deletedata = function (model) {                
                    var save = new Framework.AjaxRequestInfo("@ConfigManager.Application.BuildApiUrl("/couponcode/delete/coupon")"+'/' + model.ID(), function () {
                        console.log(save);

                        Framework.Redirector.Redirect("@Url.Action("Index", "Code")");
                    }, function () {
                    });
                    save.setParamData(couponModel);
                    Framework.AjaxManager.remove(save);
                };

                $(function () {
                    Framework.DataBinder.applyBinding(couponModel, "coupon-codes");
                    couponModel.get();
                });
     </script>

//In controller
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Record is deleted because click binding overrides onclick event. You have to put confirmation into `deletedata` function:

```
<a data-bind="click: $root.deletedata" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</a>          

            couponModel.deletedata = function (model) {   
              if (confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this record?')){
                var save = new Framework.AjaxRequestInfo("@ConfigManager.Application.BuildApiUrl("/couponcode/delete/coupon")"+'/' + model.ID(), function () {
                    console.log(save);

                    Framework.Redirector.Redirect("@Url.Action("Index", "Code")");
                }, function () {
                });
                save.setParamData(couponModel);
                Framework.AjaxManager.remove(save);
              }
            };
```

You should not mixing up ko and general js handlers.

Comment: Hi Artem and Martinez.. I tried the confirmation inside the deletedData and it worked and yes u were right, that the click binding was overriding the onclick event.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Artem but I propose more elegant way with no need to modify VM code. Just write your own `clickAndConfirm` binding that wraps original `click` binding and requests user confirmation before an action.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.clickAndConfirm = {
    init: function(el, va) {
        var message = va().message || "Sure?", action = va().action;
        var new_va = function(){
            return function(data){
                return confirm(message) && action.apply(data, arguments);
            };
        };
        arguments[1] = new_va;
        return ko.bindingHandlers.click.init.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}
```

Specify your action function and confirmation message in binding declaration:

```
<a href="#" data-bind="clickAndConfirm: { action: deletedata, message: 'Are you sure?' }">Do it!</a>
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/M5uYK/